# jquery mobile collapsible content help

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been looking at using JQM collapsible content and whilst I have understood how to use them, I cannot see a way to use with list elements. I have checked the docs and also spent time looking through google, but no go. If it is possible, I would be grateful if someone could show me how to do it. Thanks

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  <li><a href="#newintake">New Intake</a></li>
  <li><a href="#boxretrieval">Box Retrieval</a></li>
  <li><a href="#boxreturn">Box Return</a></li>
  <li><a href="#boxdestruction">Box Destruction</a></li>
  <li><a href="#permboxdestruction">Permanent Box Destruction</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/deeu8/4/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Nagivsation</li> 
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li> 
        </ul> 
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>Numeric Section</h3>
            <p>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Nagivsation</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li> 
        </ul> 
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>Alpha Section</h3>
            <p>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Phil almost. what I am trying to achieve is where you have navigation imagine that is a list item in my case #newintake. When that link is clicked, instead of going to another page the #newintake content should appear below. I suppose like a collapsible content but the link needs to be the collapsible item. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem and my best approach right now is this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
       <a href="#">
          <p>
             <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>collapsible content</p>
             </div>
          </p>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Its no so eye candy, but will do the trick with some css adjusts.

Comment: "Its no so eye candy" - love it. Don't worry, jqm isn't eye-candy in terms of code, ever.

Answer (score 1):

The path of least resistance is to not collapse the UL by hiding LI's, but instead place the UL in a div and collapse that.

Like this:

```
<a href="#" class="someButton">Click to toggle</a>

<div class="collapser">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then this JS:

```
$('.someButton').click( function() {
    $('.collapser').toggle();
});
```

Also, notice that I could have made a more complex show / hide functions that saves the current state of the collapser div... using show(), hide(), slideToggle(), fadeToggle(), etc

Comment: kristian would that work say if I wanted to just click #newintake?

Comment: kristian i tried your solution, but it dosen't work as expected. Instead of loading #newintake beneath the list element it transistions to its own page and when i return all the li are hidden. Have to refresh to show them.

Comment: i guess I'm misunderstanding what you need then. I thought the issue was that you could not make that whole list collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, jQM collapsible content is not applicable to lists. I hope it will come in the near future.

Here is my way to do it. It could be improved by adding an icon.

html:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li id="cars" data-role="list-divider" role="heading">French Cars</li>
    <li class="car"><a href="">Bugatti</a></li>
    <li class="car"><a href="">Citroen</a></li>
    <li class="car"><a href="">Ligier</a></li>
    <li class="car"><a href="">Peugeot</a></li>
    <li class="car"><a href="">Renault</a></li>
    <li class="car"><a href="">Talbot</a></li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$("#cars").click( function() {
  $(".car").toggle();
  $("#cars").toggleClass("ui-corner-bottom");
});
```

See it live:
http://jsfiddle.net/gCkZ9/3

Answer (score 0):

This is a much more dynamic & elegant solution, works with multiple lists.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li class="cars" data-role="list-divider" role="heading">French Cars</li>
    <li><a href="">Bugatti</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Citroen</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ligier</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Peugeot</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Renault</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Talbot</a></li>
</ul>



$('#cars').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-corner-bottom");
});
```